# Java, sort and display data from txt file

Tags: java, file, sorting

i'm new with java and have some trouble with one task.
i have txt file which looks like this:

```
John Doe,01-01-1980,Development,Senior Developer
Susan Smith,07-12-1983,Development,Head of Development
Ane Key,06-06-1989,BA,Junior Analyst
Nina Simone,21-09-1979,BA,Head of BA
Tom Popa,23-02-1982,Development,Developer
Tyrion Lannyster,17-03-1988,BA,Analyst
```

and i want to to sort  it by departments.
for example:
Members are :

```
[Employee Full Name] - [Employee Age] - [Employee Position] - [Employee Salary(default value x)]
```

Deparment : Development
                Members are :
                                Susan Smith ......
                                John Doe ......
                                Tom Popa ......
                Department : BA
                Members are :
                                Nina Simone .......
                                Ane Key ...........
                                Tyrion Lannyster ........

at first read file and made 2d array but can't continue how to correctly sort it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "C:\\Employees.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String SplitBy = ",";

    String myArray[][] = new String[6][5];
    int row = 0;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  

            String nums[] = line.split(SplitBy);

        for (int col = 0; col < nums.length; col++){

                String n =nums[col];

                myArray[row][col] = n;
           //     System.out.println(n);
            }               
            row++;



        }

              } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Did you search about tutorial or algoritm about this ? This should help you to start sorting your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the code solution here would not help you learn it. But I can give you hints on how to proceed. Using array is not really recommended.

**The easy, but dirty way -**

Instead of two dimensional array, use a `TreeMap<String, String[]>` where key is the department concatenated with name and value is the one dimensional array of the individual's details. As we're using `TreeMap`, the result is naturally sorted based on Department followed by Name of the person. Loop through the `entrySet` and print all the results.

**Right way -**

Define new object `Person` with all the members needed. Implement `Comparable` interface. Read all the input data, populate the same in `Person` object, add each such objects in an `ArrayList` and use Collections API's sort method to sort all the objects. Alternatively you can adapt the `Comparator` way.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)allows you to Sort as well as [util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).
You will need the arrays methods for you code, but consider moving to some sort of Collection. Perhaps a List to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would put the contents of the lines in Java Beans and then sort them using sort.

```
public User { 
    private String name;
    // ... all the fields with getters and setters
}
```

Then adapt your code to something like this:

```
// create a nice List for the users.
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            User user = new User();
            String nums[] = line.split(SplitBy);
            user.setName(nums[0]);
            // create nice method to convert String to Date
            user.setDate(convertStringToDate(nums[1]));
            // add the user to the list
            userList.add(user);

}

// Then finally sort the data according to the desired field.
Arrays.sort(userList, (a,b) -> a.name.compareTo(b.name));
```

Comment: Thanks for shearing example. added this part and worked it:

Comment: ArrayList<User> Development = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<User> BA = new ArrayList<>();
  
  for (User user : userList) {
   if (user.getDepartment().equals("Development")){
    
    Development.add(user);
   }
   else   {
    BA.add(user);
   }
  }
  
  System.out.println("Department Development:");
  for (User user : Development) {
   System.out.println(" \t " + user.getName() + " " + user.getPosition()); 
  }
  System.out.println("Department Ba:");
  for (User user : BA) {
   System.out.println(" \t " + user.getName() + " " + user.getPosition());